# Regex to find value between two Angel braces text << value >>j

Tags: javascript

I am looking to get value SPR2 from below string

```
var myString = "BUILDING - WITH DELETION OF EXCLUSION (d) & (e)<<SPR2>>"
```

please help

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write such a regex yourself yet?

Comment: And what research have you done? There are many many similar questions already on this site as well as other web searches. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing or *"do my research for me"* service

Comment: I can completely understand that but I an new in regex expressions and I am not getting any way to think what is alternative or productive way to get value.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please identify what solutions you have tried before asking for assistance on Stack Overflow.

The expression you are looking for is `(<{2}\w+>{2})`, as demonstrated [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=104611).

You would then take a substring of each match and remove the << and >> characters.

Start to end, the solution would be as follows:

```js
var str = 'BUILDING - WITH DELETION OF EXCLUSION (d) & (e)<<SPR2>>';
var regex = /<{2}(\w+)>{2}/g;
var matches = str.match(regex);

matches.forEach(function(match) {
  console.log(match.substring(match.indexOf('<<') + 2, match.lastIndexOf('>>')));
});
```

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. I want to get value inside angle braces. The required result is  SPR2 not <<SPR2>>.

Comment: @viralshah that's exactly what @adam-chubbuck provided you. Click on run code snippet and it will give you `SPR2` as the required result.